# "global" does not work in CakePHP 2.1.1 views

Tags: php, php-5.3, global

I am using PHP 5.3.8 with CakePHP 2.1.1.

This is my view (the layout is empty, actually it only outputs the view itself)

```
<?php   
// $present is not a view variable
$present = 'Hello World!';

class ApplicationsPDF
{   
    public function CreateApplicationTable()
    {
        global $present;
        exit(var_dump($present));
    }
}


$pdf = new ApplicationsPDF();
$pdf->CreateApplicationTable();
?>
```

The output is `null` instead of "Hello World!".

If I copy and paste this code into a single file (which I directly run from the browser), it perfectly works!

So it must be a CakePHP bug. Does anyone know it?

Comment: I can't imagine a bug this significant hasn't been caught before but there's nothing about it in the 5.3.9+ changelogs. I have to imagine it's something about your local environment. Are you using auto_prepend_file to munge anything?

Comment: No but the code above is run from CakePHP 2.1.1. I just figured out that the code perfectly runs standalone. I'll edit the question. (I know that Stackoverflow is not a bug tracker but I didn't want to delete this question)

Comment: I know it's not the point, but why do you think you need to use global variables? Why not pass `$present` into the constructor and set a class variable?

Comment: @Madmartigan You're totally right! I already wanted to refactor it but then I found this bug ;)

Comment: Yes, the code posted above is my complete view file (after reducing the code down to the bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a PHP nor a CakePHP bug!

It's because CakePHP includes the view in its view class so the declared variables aren't really in the global scope and `global` has no effect.

From ADmad ([source](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2739-global-keyword-does-not-work-in-view-files#ticket-2739-3)):

> When you run the file by itself your assignment $testVar = 'Hello
>   World!' is in global context hence things work like you expected them
>   to. But when it is used as a view file, the file is included within a
>   View class function hence its no longer in global context and $testVar
>   is no longer a global var, hence your expectation is incorrect. Using
>   global variables in an OOP framework is a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the global keyword before the class definition:

```
global $present;

class ApplicationsPDF
{   
    public function CreateApplicationTable()
    {
        exit(var_dump($present));
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work and gives me an `Undefined variable` error in `CreateApplicationTable()`.

Comment: You didn't remove the `$present` variable declaration part, did you?

Comment: I didn't but then `$present` will never be defined (it's not a view variable).